# How to use Logs for real time debug ? python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, debugging

I am running a long backend process on google app engine , using modules.
the process  take more than one hour.

I am using logging.info to debug my code, but the problem that I couldn't check my debugs on google console until the process finish.

is there a way to check the debug info while the process running ? in real time !

thanks

Comment: Are you debugging  a live application? Or using dev_appserver

Comment: @TimCastelijns I am using live application !

Comment: Is there a reason you are testing it while its live, and not testing with dev_appserver first?

Comment: yes I couldn't test using dev_appserver, because there is a lot of options, and it's will take a lot of time to build my data on dev_appserver  !